# How to update the text of a TextBox on the same page in the GridViewRowCommand Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Hi I've a Gridview and a textbox which are placed in an Ajax updatepanel.

The source is given below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelAdmissionDefaultSettings" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewMeritDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#5C5C5C" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="MeritGridStyle" 
            onrowdatabound="GridViewMeritDetails_RowDataBound" 
            onrowcommand="GridViewMeritDetails_RowCommand">
<RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Field Name" DataField="MeritField" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Field ID" DataField="MeritFieldID" />
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="edit" HeaderText="Edit" Text="Edit" />
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="delete" HeaderText="Delete" Text="Delete" />
</Columns>
<FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>


<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxMeritFieldName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My problem is, when I click edit button in GridView, I want to display the value in a cell in the selected row in the textbox. I've given the code to display it in Gridview RowCommand event. But it's not working.

Here is the code behind:

```
protected void GridViewMeritDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int iRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    if (e.CommandName == "edit")
    {
        TextBoxMeritFieldName.Enabled = true;
        TextBoxMeritFieldName.Text = GridViewMeritDetails.Rows[iRowIndex].Cells[0].Text.Trim();
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "delete")
    {
        //Add code to delete merit field
    }
}
```

When I debugged, the control enters the RowCommand and reaches the line

```
TextBoxMeritFieldName.Text = GridViewMeritDetails.Rows[iRowIndex].Cells[0].Text.Trim();
```

But the text is not displayed on the page. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Set mode of UpdatePanel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="UpdatePanelAdmissionDefaultSettings" runat="server" >
```

Comment: I  tried this. But it didn't help. Thank you for taking effort helping me out.

Comment: Use UpdateMode="Conditional" instead of Mode, I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel Mode="Conditional" ID="UpdatePanelAdmissionDefaultSettings" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:GridView ID="GridViewMeritDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#5C5C5C" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="MeritGridStyle" 
        onrowdatabound="GridViewMeritDetails_RowDataBound" 
        onrowcommand="GridViewMeritDetails_RowCommand">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
       <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Field Name" DataField="MeritField" />
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Field ID" DataField="MeritFieldID" />
          <asp:ButtonField CommandName="edit" HeaderText="Edit" Text="Edit" />
          <asp:ButtonField CommandName="delete" HeaderText="Delete" Text="Delete" />
       </Columns>
       <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
       <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
       <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
       <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
       <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
  </asp:GridView>


 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxMeritFieldName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Set one property `Mode="Conditional"` of update panel

Comment: It doesn't make my code work. But I got my answer and thank you for trying to help me out.

Comment: :The EventName property of AsyncPostBackTrigger is optional. If not specified, the DefaultEventAttribute attribute of the control is used to determine the default event.

I found it here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.eventname.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for your generous reply.

I've got the answer.

I added the following line of code in the UpdatePanelAdmissionDefaultSettings  section

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridViewMeritDetails" />
```

Now it becomes:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel Mode="Conditional" ID="UpdatePanelAdmissionDefaultSettings" runat="server">
```

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxMeritFieldName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridViewMeritDetails" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And I'm getting result as I needed. Earlier, my Triggers section was like this:

```
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridViewMeritDetails" EventName="RowCommand"/>
</Triggers>
```

I just removed the EventName attribute and it works now...